# Do I have to reinstall cuda after changing the graphic card

Tags: c++, cuda, hardware

Last week my graphic card Nvidia (Cuda 2.0) stopped working and I had to plug in an old one which only supports Cuda 1.1. I have the NVidia Cuda 5.0 Toolkit installed. The project still compiles, but I get a runtime error. Therefore, my question is: do I have to reinstall Cuda again or change other settings in the cuda toolkit if I change the graphic card?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Maybe you have to reinstall your graphics card driver. Also, are you by chance still compiling the code for your old compute capability when you are recompiling it?

Comment: You shouldn't have to reinstall anything.  Your project may have been compiled for a cc2.0 device, in which case you would have to recompile for a cc 1.1 device.  It's possible that other issues could crop up as well, such as too many resources requested for launch.  You will need to decode the error and determine the reason why you are getting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA sdk is the same whatever your NVIDIA card but you should need to install the right driver. But you might change some settings in the code..

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I changed the graphic card again to one which supports cuda 3.0 without re-installing the cuda toolkit and compiled the project again and it worked. So I guess the error has to do with the required recources which cause the runtime error on the old cuda 1.1 grpahic card.

Comment: To add more description on this issue with a Quadro card, you need to install Quadro ODE graphics driver to use CUDA with the card.